# how this transform is possible with bayesian rule?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I read a article about ont-shot learning from wiki.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-shot_learning

From there, in bayesian framework section,
they said that $p(I|I_t,O_{fg})$ = $\int p(I|\theta,O_{fg})p(\theta|I_t,O_{fg}) d\theta$,
where $\theta$ is the parameters for $O_{fg}$ (foreground class).

how is this transformation possible?

Comment: They are just marginalizing out $\theta$, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution.

Comment: @Thoth, could you explain it more for me? how is it equal after marginalizing out the right hand side?